# Azure Bot Microsoft Teams Autocomplete/Suggestion similar to "Who" but dynamic

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

In the who bot for MS Teams, suggestions will auto populate to help the user to enter a command.

[image: Who Behavior]

In my research, this feature can be enjoyed by other bots by editing the Manifest file. Is there some other way to facilitate this behavior more dynamically? I'd really like to be able to provide recent history of say the last 10 commands and have that auto-populate, but don't see a way to do this.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any other way apart from adding commands to your bot. To define a set of core commands that your bot can respond to, you can add a command menu with a drop-down list of commands for your bot. The list of commands is presented to the users in the compose message area when they are in conversation with your bot.

Answer (score 0):

Command menu with a drop-down list of commands is added for your bot, to define a set of core commands that your bot can respond to. The list of commands is presented to the users in the compose message area when they are in conversation with your bot. You can add those commands list in manifest file of your bot app where these are defined.
[image]

Comment: Ya, thanks, I knew about the manifest approach, but this is static. I was just hoping there was some way to make this behavior dynamic. As I mentioned, I wanted to add a feature to recall recent history of commands. Today, I capture and store the last 10 commands that a user has requested. I was hoping I could do the same as the manifest approach but with these stored values. I can implement a "history" command but these would just return as an Activity response and not as an autocomplete/suggestion.

Comment: Currently we do not have any dynamic way to add commands or suggestions in manifest. However you can add suggested actions to a message as follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-add-suggested-actions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#send-suggested-actions

Comment: OK, thanks. Maybe I missed that before. I think this approach could be nice.